# Data structure to maintain a pair of files

Tags: python, multithreading, algorithm, data-structures, filesystems

## Background

There are two files with name `alertfile` & `eventfile`.

This file pair is sitting in multiple folders(shown below), with each file pair having different content.

Only way to recognise the names of file pair different from other pair is through the folder structure, they sit in.

Files will always be opened in read-only mode using python file api in Linux.

With respect to content, One file pair has no relation with other file pair.

No clue on the depth of folder structure.

Folder names are unknown(in advance).

Every folder may not have these file pairs. Some folder may have only sub-folders that have these file pairs. So, a folder can be just empty.

Size of each file pair is KB's in size and are static files.

```
root_folder
 |
 |
 +---folder1
 |       | 
 |       |___ alertfile
 |       |___ eventfile
 |
 +---folder2
 |       |
 |       |___ alertfile
 |       |___ eventfile
 |       |
 |       +--- folder_2_1
 |            |
 |            |___alertfile
 |            |___eventfile
 |            |
 |            +---folder_2_1_1
 |                |
 |                |___alertfile
 |                |___eventfile
 |          
 |      
 +---folder3
 |       |
 |       |___ alertfile
 |       |___ eventfile
 |
 +---folder4
 |       |
 |       +---folder4_1
 |             |
 |             |____ alertfile
 |             |____ eventfile
 |             |
 |             +---folder4_1_1(empty) 
 :
 :
 :
```

---

## Goal

There is a need to access the content of all these file pairs in different areas of code, for different purpose.

---

Program is a server program... that maintains the cache of these set of file pairs...

1) Which data structure should I use to efficiently access these file pairs? to actually parse the content in these file pairs....for multiple reasons

2) Does it be faster to have content of each file pair, in a pair of data structures? and keyed with a folder path..

3) Can the file-reading be multi threaded before creating the cache? Because python GIL allows IO bound threads to interleave..

Comment: Are folders always logically named like you listed, with index on each level?

Comment: Do you know all the vendor names on each level in advance, or is there a need to search for sub-folders given a level of folder?

Comment: @blhsing There is a need to search for sub_folders given a level of folder. I definitely do not know the vendor names on each level, in advance.. No clue on the depth of folder structure.

Comment: @blhsing Yes, folder names are unknown(in advance).

Comment: Does every folder have these two files, including the root folder? Or can some of them not have these file pairs?

Comment: @blhsing Every folder may not have these two files. Some folder may have sub-folders that have these files.. Query edited for this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using nested dicts to cache your `alertfile` and `eventfile` pairs. Since a folder may or may not contain the file pairs, when it does, it should use the `'.'` key to store a dict of the file pairs in this folder, like this:

```
cache = {
    '.': {'alertfile': 'alert content', 'eventfile': 'event content'},
    'hello': {
        'foo': {'.': {'alertfile': 'alert content', 'eventfile': 'event content'}},
        'bar': {'.': {'alertfile': 'alert content', 'eventfile': 'event content'}}
    },
    'world': {
        'aloha': {
            '.': {'alertfile': 'alert content', 'eventfile': 'event content'},
            'hi': {'.': {'alertfile': 'alert content', 'eventfile': 'event content'}},
            'hey': {'.': {'alertfile': 'alert content', 'eventfile': 'event content'}}
        }
    },
    'empty': {}
}
```

And here is a recursive function that scans a given directory, reads any of the file pairs within, and returns a dict in the above data structure.

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isdir, join

def scan_files(dir):
    cache = {}
    for name in listdir(dir):
        path = join(dir, name)
        if isdir(path):
            cache[name] = scan_files(path)
        elif name in ('alertfile', 'eventfile'):
            with open(path, 'r') as file:
                cache['.'][name] = file.read()
    return cache
```

You can put the block inside the `for` loop above into a thread pool if you wish to speed up the process.

Or, if you prefer to cache the files in a flat dict, you can use [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) instead to traverse the entire directory in a loop.

```
import os
def scan_files(dir):
    cache = {}
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir):
        for name in files:
            if name in ('alertfile', 'eventfile'):
                path = os.path.join(root, name)
                with open(path, 'r') as file:
                    cache[path] = file.read()
    return cache
```

Comment: Dictionaries of dictionaries

Comment: Why would you not recommend a simple dictionary with keys as folder path? This would help traverse dictionary in O(1)

Comment: Because I need to traverse this cache multiple times and folder path must always logically be unique.

Comment: I recommended a nested dict because you said you didn't know any vendor names in advance. It has the advantage of being able to list the subfolders of a folder quickly by allowing you to loop through the keys of a dict at any level. With a flat dict indexed by full paths you will have to scan through the entire list of dict keys in order to find all the subfolders of a folder. If you do want to use a flat dict instead you can simply use [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) to build your dict.

Comment: But I have such two root folders that I maintain cache(for each) and compare the cache, based on the key. I evaluate value 1 in cache1 with value2 in cache2, if key1 is equal to key2. This is the goal. For this, nested dictionary would not work.

Comment: @overexchange Nested dict would work but a flat dict is certainly easier if comparing two caches is your primary use case. I've added a function that caches the files as a flat dict to my answer then.